# How to convert HTML page to PDF in YII framework

Tags: html, pdf, yii

[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06rBI.png) I need to convert my HTML page  to PDF format in YII framework.
I have tried `HTML2PDF` where it gives me this error.

> [ERROR] It seems that HTML2PDF dependencies are not installed… you must install them with composer install

Then I have installed composer also. But the error is same.

Suggest me solution of this or give any new idea.

this is my view code..

```
<tr>
    <?php echo "<td>".$record->inv_article."</td>" ?>
    <?php echo "<td>".$record->inv_no."</td>" ?>
    <?php echo "<td >".$record->inv_weight."</td>" ?>
    <?php echo "<td >".$record->inv_amt."</td>" ?>
    <?php echo "<td >".$record->inv_freight."</td>" ?>
    <?php echo "<td >".$record->inv_bilticharges."</td>" ?>
    <?php echo "<td >".$record->inv_bilticharges."</td>" ?>


    <?php $i++; ?>

</tr>
```

Here is my controller in my project

```
public function actionGeneratePDF($id){

    $mpdf1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

    $myhtml=$this->renderPartial('lorryprint', array(
        'model'=>$model,'invid'=>$id), true);


    $mpdf1->WriteHTML($myhtml);

    $file_name= $id.'.pdf';

    ob_end_clean();

    $mpdf1->Output($file_name,EYiiPdf::OUTPUT_TO_DOWNLOAD );
}
```

[CHECK OUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbrNr.png)

Comment: no one is able to ans my questions ??????????????

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem couple of months ago, I wanted to convert the html page into pdf in Yii Framework. It took me 3 days to find out how to use it properly. So there are two ways to generate PDF from html by using PHP classes below:

1. `HTML2PDF`
2. `mPDF`

I have used both but I will prefer you to use `mPDF`. it is much better than `HTML2PDF`. Here is method on How to use `mPDF` in Yii Framework.

First of all you need

[**YiiPDF**](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/files/yii-pdf-0.3.2.zip) - Small Yii extension, that wraps a few PHP libraries (mPDF and HTML2PDF so far) to convert HTML to PDF.

[**mPDF**](http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/MPDF_5_7.zip) - is a PHP class to generate PDF files from HTML with Unicode/UTF-8 and CJK support.

I have used `mPDF Version 5.7` Because you don't need a composer to install it.

So just download `Yii PDF` and `mPDF` from above links and extract them and then Rename the folders to `yii-pdf` and `mpdf` and place them into your project in `protected\extensions`.

Then open your `protected/config/main.php` and add the below code.

```
'components'=>array(
    'ePdf' => array(
        'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
        'params'        => array(
            'mpdf'     => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.extensions.mpdf.*',
                'constants'         => array(
                    '_MPDF_TEMP_PATH' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime'),
                ),
                'class'=>'mpdf', // the literal class filename to be loaded from the vendors folder
                /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184
                    'mode'              => '', //  This parameter specifies the mode of the new document.
                    'format'            => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'default_font_size' => 0, // Sets the default document font size in points (pt)
                    'default_font'      => '', // Sets the default font-family for the new document.
                    'mgl'               => 15, // margin_left. Sets the page margins for the new document.
                    'mgr'               => 15, // margin_right
                    'mgt'               => 16, // margin_top
                    'mgb'               => 16, // margin_bottom
                    'mgh'               => 9, // margin_header
                    'mgf'               => 9, // margin_footer
                    'orientation'       => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                )*/
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Please note: In above code `'class' => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',` means that you have a file called `EYiiPdf` in `protected/extensions/yii-pdf/` and similarly that mPDF extension `'librarySourcePath' => 'application.extensions.mpdf.*',` exists in `protected/extensions/mpdf`

Then you can create a function in your controller.

```
public function actionGeneratePDF($id){

    $model = AsfiUsers::model()->findByPk($id);

    $mpdf1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

    $myhtml=$this->renderPartial('ProfileView', array(
        'personal_info'=>$model), true);

    $mpdf1->WriteHTML($myhtml);

    $file_name= $id.'.pdf';

    ob_end_clean();

    $mpdf1->Output($file_name,EYiiPdf::OUTPUT_TO_DOWNLOAD );
}
```

So in my View in `ProfileView` I have added a button at the top of it.

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('PDF Version',array('AsfiUser/GeneratePDF','id'=>$this->id), array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-sm')); ?>
```

After click on that button, It will download the PDF of that html page. My Profile View has tables too so Thats why I have used `mPDF` not `Html2PDF`. In html2pdf, It doesnot give much options to adjust tables margin etc. But in mpdf it is automatically adjust and will be a perfect PDF.

**FOR HTML2PDF**

In case if you want to use `HTML2PDF`, all the steps are same. Just download `Old version of html2pdf`, New version will have problem like `dependencies are not installed`. Just like you have them now.

All steps are same, just add this into your `protected/config/main.php` below the mPDF class in yii-pdf component array.

```
            'HTML2PDF' => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.extensions.html2pdf.*',
                'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap
                /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil
                    'orientation' => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                    'format'      => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'language'    => 'en', // language: fr, en, it ...
                    'unicode'     => true, // TRUE means clustering the input text IS unicode (default = true)
                    'encoding'    => 'UTF-8', // charset encoding; Default is UTF-8
                    'marges'      => array(5, 5, 5, 8), // margins by default, in order (left, top, right, bottom)
                )*/
            )
```

and then your controller function will be same just replace the name with mPDF.

```
public function actionGeneratePDF($id){

    $model = AsfiUsers::model()->findByPk($id);

    $html2pdf= Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();

    $myhtml=$this->renderPartial('ProfileView', array(
        'personal_info'=>$model), true);

    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($myhtml);

    $file_name= $id.'.pdf';

    ob_end_clean();

    $html2pdf->Output($file_name,EYiiPdf::OUTPUT_TO_DOWNLOAD );
}
```

and create the same button in view for it. I hope it will work for you. I have used the same and working perfectly.

**UPDATED**:

This code works, just try to check you haven't made any mistake and secondly add this below code at the top of your html view file.

```
<?php
ob_start(); //started buffering
?>
<?php echo CHtml::link('PDF Version',array('AsfiUser/GeneratePDF','id'=>$this->id), array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-sm')); ?>
```

It will add the button on the page which u want to make PDF, when u click on the button, it will download the file while it will take few seconds to a minute depending on page size.

**Updated 2**

add this line to ur controller

`$myhtml=preg_replace("/<\\/?a(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "", $myhtml);`

So your controller will be like this

```
public function actionGeneratePDF($id){

$mpdf1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

$myhtml=$this->renderPartial('lorryprint', array(
    'model'=>$model,'invid'=>$id), true);
$myhtml=preg_replace("/<\\/?a(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "", $myhtml);

$mpdf1->WriteHTML($myhtml);

$file_name= $id.'.pdf';

ob_end_clean();

$mpdf1->Output($file_name,EYiiPdf::OUTPUT_TO_DOWNLOAD );
}
```

**OR**

If the above controller part doesnot work then fix ur code.

Your this line says `$model`

```
$myhtml=$this->renderPartial('lorryprint', array(
    'model'=>$model,'invid'=>$id), true);
```

and in ur view you are using `$record` instead of $model, Have u done it properly in ur loop. Is ur View file showing results or not?

If it is showing properly,then ur view file `lorryprint` should be like this. add `<td>` outside the php tag.

```
<?php
ob_start(); //started buffering
?>
<?php echo CHtml::link('PDF Version',array('AsfiUser/GeneratePDF','id'=>$this->id), array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-sm')); ?>

//more code here
<td><?php echo $record->inv_article;?></td>
<td><?php echo $record->inv_no;?></td>
<td><?php echo $record->inv_weight;?></td>
<td><?php echo $record->inv_amt;?></td>
<td><?php echo $record->inv_freight;?></td>
<td><?php echo $record->inv_bilticharges;?></td>
<td><?php echo $record->inv_bilticharges;?></td>
<?php $i++; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!. Buit it returns an blank pdf. we want it to give show all the values as same on the HTML Page

Comment: Alright, Follow the step properly, it will work and i have add `ob_start()` at view file, check my updated answer at the bottom.

Comment: hi.. it shows output only  as +div element+  in pdf

Comment: Can you show the full code of your View file and also a screenshot of pdf. Update ur question with the code and screenshot.

Comment: Check the updated 2 in my answer, I hope it will solve ur problem.

Comment: i tried all steps.. but not working.. i stiil have the same error as  +div element+

Comment: pls check image above

Comment: The image is of PDF screenshot, show me the image of view file and post full code of view.

Comment: Asfi Tanoli  i can't post my code here.. but it gives same error on pdf page.. pls gice some solution

Comment: There must be some errors in ur View Page in Div tags or you are not using the `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean()` properly. The code is working perfectly for me. My View Page has all types of Data, Paragraphs, Tables, Links etc.

Comment: I emailed you, and there is no error in mpdf.php. The error must be in php. Google about it. CHeck ur php version etc